# How to bypass pop-up blocker in this JS Alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open a new tab/pop-up when the user press ok or cancel, but it's not working if the user has the pop-up blocker on.

```
var openAlert = window.confirm("Click ok if you want to go to Google.com");
if (openAlert) { // if they clicked "ok"
    window.open(
      'http://google.com', 
      '_blank'
    );
} else { // if they clicked "cancel"
    window.open(
      'http://example.com/example.html', 
      '_blank'
    );
}
```

Does anyone have a solution to bypass that?

Comment: If this could be done then why do you think pop blockers would have existed in the first place?

Comment: Nopes. See @DarinDimitrov Comment.

Comment: I know that exit some workaround when the user make the event (for example, clink in a button), so the pop blocker wouldn't matter. I think there is always a solution for everything.

Comment: use a link element (created and clicked in JS, with a target _blank), don't use window.open.

Answer (score 1):

Use `target="_blank"` as a target of the link you clicked. You can style links as buttons. Use Javascript just to show the alert and to block the click action.

Comment: This is a **HACK**! `:P`

Comment: But this doesn't work. Because, he is getting the info from the `confirm()`'s return value.

Comment: nice thing about hacks: if people use them for 10 years, they become a standard. Just unspecced =) @PraveenKumar which is fine: you can create an "a" element and click it in JS.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans LoL No man... Well... Yes that works. `:P`

Comment: Hey @GolezTrol, sorry for asking much, but could how that would be in code? I didn't got you ):

Comment: I think you don't even need to click the link from Javascript. You can just capture the click event, and use `event.preventDefault()` to block the click if the user clicks 'cancel'. Without it the link should behave as normal.

Comment: @user2852724 Have a look at my answer. Have code for you.

Comment: It would be possible without clicking in a button from the screen?

Comment: @user2852724 Yes, that's without clicking a button.

Comment: @GolezTrol because of security issues there (you can change the link destination of an <a> element in the DOM that way), depending on the browsers settings that may not work for everyone. A fresh `<a>` with `a.click()` in the openAlert handling, however, always works.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JS created link, and follow that:
    var body = $(document.body);

```
function promptFlow() {
    // SO/jsbin/etc don't allow alert/prompt/confirm/etc, so we use a quick proxy:
    var div = $("<div><p>want to go to google</p><button>OK</button></div>");
    var openAlert = false;
    div.find("button").click(function() {
      div.remove();
      openAlert = true;

      // your code would be the following:
      if (openAlert) {
        var a = $("<a>").attr({
          href: 'https://google.com',
          target: '_blank'
        }).appendTo(body);
        // click as HTML element, not jquery element
        a[0].click();
        // then, remove it.
        a.remove();
      }

    });

    body.append(div);
}

$("button").click(promptFlow);
```

This won't work as snippet, because of how SO embeds snippets, but http://jsbin.com/vipolegefe/edit?html,js,output shows this working just fine.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, but the intention was it working inside the js alert. Not with a button.

Comment: protip: read the comments in the code. Neither SO nor jsbin *allow* alert, prompt, confirm, etc, so in order to show this working, we need a quick and dirty confirm proxy.